Writing additional kernel layer on UART driver
I want to take leverage the existing kernel API/module to create packet layer abstraction for user space application to transfer "packets" via UART interface.
So, the intention is a kernel module that does the following

Uses different module to read UART bytes (I'm not sure what I should use, I can see "usbserial" available, but not sure if it can be extended that way)

After reading a certain number of bytes do some calculation on in, like crc, type etc. And then transfers the packet to the user space program

User space program can use poll mechanism to get notified, and then read the entire packet.


How can I build such a thing? I'm having trouble connecting the pieces, and google/chatgpt is not helping. Any example that does something similar would be awesome, thanks!
edit:
As a packet I'm referring to an internal data structure, nothing to do with any networking protocol, it's literally.
struct comms_packet {
 uint8_t length;
 uint8_t type;
 uint8_t data[PACKET_DATA_LEN];
 uint8_t crc; };


I don't know about implementing it in the kernel, but it might be more usual to do it within the application, or with a library or even with a separate process providing the packet service over a socket or such

@ilkkachu yes I'm aware it's overkill, but I just wanted to create such a thing to learn. There would be no interaction with HW itself, as another module would provide that, so it should be relatively easy.

What bit rate are you intending to use?  Most circuitry/chipsets in the UART class have top speeds that are quite slow compared to network interface speeds.  This is why network connections quickly moved off serial ports and modems as soon as network cards became cheap enough in the 1990s.

@SottoVoce as I said, it's just to learn a thing in Kernel, and for fun.

@konradk btw, what you describe exists in various forms and implementations; the most generic one I can think of is SLIP. Even the much more modern PPP is still already very old!

What you describe exists:
PPP is supported by the linux kernel out of the box, as is the HDLC framing you'd use over serial lines. For info how to make that work with pppd negotiating the connection and then letting the kernel handle the rest: 
ppp between two machines over serial without a modem
Now, as I mentioned in the comments about this, PPP (and its SLIP predecessor even more so) are positively ancient code in the linux kernel, mostly. You can copy that, but it might not be an experience in how you should write something today!

realize you need to do a few things:

Framing: something needs to look at the bytes coming out of your serial port and be like "ah yes, here's where a data frame starts and ends!". The other end needs to encapsulate packets into such detectable frames.
Configuration: something has to generally "set up the whole thing", pick/assign network addresses
Routing: something must be like "oh yes, you have a packet for   fd16:dead:cafe:d00d::0002? Sure, this way!" to IP packets.

The first step here is probably realizing a sensible userland/kernel functionality split. Routing should clearly be done by the kernel. Configuration very likely in userland. Framing?
You can see that in the split between the kernel PPP driver and the userland pppd program: Not all aspects need to be handled in the kernel, to begin with – and doing things in the kernel makes them harder to develop for, worse to make mistakes in, and unrestricted in access. So, usually, avoid doing things in the kernel that can be done elsewhere! PPP infrastructure for Linux is a bit older, and a lot of things have become available since then, so that design choices might (I wager: would) be different if someone was to implement the same today.
With UARTs, by technical reason why they are UARTs, being generally slow compared to the processing speed of Linux computers today (not 30 years ago), there's little reason to implement the framing in the kernel – a userland process opening a serial port device file, interacting with that to set it up at desired baudrate, parity etc, and then getting bytes in and out will be plenty fast enough even for a 10 Mb/s "not actually a UART, but behaving like one" serial ports. The same process can use select/poll/epoll/io_uring functionality to not have to block all the time (or to reduce the number of IO calls it does to reduce the number of context switches, in the case of io_uring). But it can also be written first just doing read and write in blocking ways, and when that works, can the serial-device-facing part be extended to do something more elegant, if (and only if) that would have an advantage at all (benchmark/profile your things before optimizing them!).
So, you'd write something that is a framing protocol finite state machine (FSM) (very central protocol and generally digital logic concept – if you're not familiar with FSMs, read wikipedia), in a userland program. You need one FSM for the transmitting side and one for the receiving, on both ends (you would typically have a "super" FSM that supervises these two, and for example resets the transmitter if the receiver encounters an error)
That program would have a receiver framing FSM and a transmitter framing FSM. 
The receiver FSM would then do something like having a "SEARCH" state where it looks for a start-of-frame marker string of bytes in what it gets from the serial device, discarding everything before; a "SOF FOUND" state when that has been found, discarding all bytes from the start-of-frame marker and reading the header bytes that tell it how many bytes to expect from the following data sequence, a "DATA" mode, where it receives as many bytes from the serial line, and then hands of this data to the part of your software that builds a network packet out of that, and then reverts back to the "SEARCH" state.
The "builds a network packet out of that" is easy on Linux; you'd just get a tun device, and put the bytes from the data part on there as network packet as receiver. Conversely, for the transmitting part, you take the data packets as bytes and feed them into the transmitting FSM.
So that's your "network via UART" driver – no kernel coding involved, because that would usually be the way writing something like this.

Now, assuming you want to forgo "doing it sensibly" and rather "do it anyways" and put this code in the kernel – you'd still write the userland implementation first! Gives you something to verify things work that is much easier to develop and debug and doesn't take down your machine if you happen to have a bug in a buffer handler or something.
But as soon as you've done that and have settled on how the protocol FSMs work, you can certainly move the state machines into a linux kernel module, and let that do roughly what linux/drivers/net/ppp/ppp_async.c does. You'll find routines that check the current state, and that fill data into skb (network socket data buffer data type) objects; you implement a network device (alloc_netdev) that can be configured via netlink (so that you can somehow tell it which serial device to use, for example); then add a device node (so, a "pseudo-file" to be put under /dev) that a user can do ioctl on to configure your module, or you just let it all be statically defined at module load time using module parameters passed to modprobe / insmod. You add the generic layer (in the PPP case, that's in ppp_generic.c), which then goes, sets up the net device, kicks off all the state machines.
Make sure to realize that the kernel might well be running on multiple cores, and that if you exchange data between transmit and receive side, you need to use the kernel locking mechanism, so to not overwrite data that's currently being read. You will need to put your receive and transmit handling into kernel tasklets to let them run in parallel.

Hi, thanks for the answer Marcus.
To be precise, this packet I'm referring is not related to network.
It's literally
struct comms_packet {
uint8_t length;
uint8_t type;
uint8_t data[PACKET_DATA_LEN];
uint8_t crc;
};
It's just to update software on an STM32. I have both code for PC and STM32, just wanted to write something challenging (but reachable) in the kernel itself.

So the interface would be like
open_packet_device("serial_device_name") <- this should return  a handle and alloc resources in the kernel for that specific process, and do validation. Not I'm not sure how to implement that, maybe such function like socket(2), are just "write(2)" wrappers underhood?
and then I could use descriptor to poll for entire packets. And also have some filesystem extension to e.g. print stats of the FSM.
So is PPP is valid example?
I found kernel so hard to find any information to develop, it feels like obfuscated.

uff, then you asked something extremely different than what you actually needed!

(none of what you describe here in the comments even remotely sounds like you would do it in the kernel, though.)

Yes, I should have described that more explicitly.

well, now that you've described it: this is really just: use your serial device directly from your userland program; nothing you can do in the kernel really enhances the functionality you would get that way.
